# Unable to edit the database with placed in a MVC pattern

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a Controller folder with controller.php; a Model folder with db-manager.php, table-user.php and a footer.html. The controller.php has the db-manager include, the db-manager contains a function that connects toward the database and a function with an sql update inside.

db-manager.php

```
 public function change_password($id, $password)
    {
        $sql = "UPDATE user SET password = :password WHERE id = :id;";
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(":password", $password);
        $stmt->bindParam(":id", $id);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
```

controller.php

```
require_once "../Model/account-db-manager.php";
if (isset($_POST['userId']) && isset($_POST['changePassword'])) {
    $userId = $_POST['userId'];
    $password = $_POST['changePassword'];

    $database->change_password($userId, $password);
}
```

What i've been trying to do is have to click a row with edit btn and open a modal that would allow me to input a password, once i submit, it would update the database.
This is my jquery:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.editbtn').click(function () {
            var userId = $(this).attr('id');
            $('#userId').val(userId);
        });

        $('#changePassForm').submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault(); 
            var newPassword = $('#changePassword').val();

            var userId = $('#userId').val();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'Controller/account-controller.php', 
                data: {
                    userId: userId,
                    changePassword: newPassword
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    location.reload();
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

When I try the code nothing get's updated. I'm expecting the code to update the trying to make a MVC pattern php